# Build and update GUI status/progress bar

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I couldn't find a functioning answer for this question I have. I want to construct a python GUI that will display the health, damage/shot, fire rate, time to kill, shots to kill, pretty much every variable that is in this code, but I have no idea how to construct what I need. It needs to be a simple window with a colored bar (like a download percentage bar) in the middle with a button below it to activate the simulation (how fast death would actually occur to be shot with this particular weapon)and labels above in a sort of list. When the bar empties (from full health to zero health in real time) it needs to stay, so somehow I also need a button to refresh the simulation with all the same variable values. Here is my code (that does exactly what I need it to do save the GUI portion):

```
#import module for update frequency
import threading

#user inputs health
health = float(input("Enter health:"))

#user inputs how much damage each bullet does
dps = float(input("Enter Damage per shot:"))

#user inputs the fire rate of the weapon
spm = float(input("Enter Fire Rate:"))

#from user inputs establish how many shots it takes to reduce health to or below zero
if ((health / dps).is_integer()) is False: #checks if the stk value will be a float
    stk = int(health / dps) + 1 #since stk value is a float go up to next whole number. 33dps doesn't kill in 3 shots.
else: #if stk value is an integer, establishes stk variable
    stk = health / dps

delay_in_seconds = float(60 / spm)

#establishes the time to kill in seconds, take one from stk to account for delay of gunfire    
ttk = ((stk - 1) * delay_in_seconds)

#test on how to test for frequency of updating GUI once I figure out how in the heck to build it
def DPS_Timer():
    threading.Timer(float((ttk/stk)), DPS_Timer).start()

#calls my god forsaken function
DPS_Timer()
```

Any GUI module will suffice, I was trying with Tkinter and it never worked out for me. I also read the Tkinter documentation for Python 2.7.13 and I couldn't figure out quite what I needed to do. Also, as an example, if it took 4 shots to kill an enemy player, and those 4 shots occurred over a minute, this progress/status bar would need to reduce (health/stk)% every (ttk/stk) seconds. so at 100 health, 25% every 15 seconds.

Comment: Your question is a bit complex and cannot be thoroughly answered here. I personally use PyQt5. There is a designer (http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) where you can put all the loading bars and push buttons you want using your mouse. Then you'll need to link each to your functions. If you never wrote a GUI, be prepared for the learning curve. It could be easier not to use designer if you're ok with "drawing blindly".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my very messy testing code to solve my GUI issue. Still not 100% what I want on the ttk.Progressbar() but it does it's job save when it reaches 100% it resets before stopping.

```
#import module for update frequency and gui. ttk for progressbar
import threading,ttk
from Tkinter import *

#establishes counter for testing purposes
counter = 0

#establish window
root = Tk()

def main():
    #user inputs health
    health = float(input("Enter health:"))

    #user inputs how much damage each bullet does
    dps = float(input("Enter Damage per shot:"))

    #user inputs the fire rate of the weapon
    spm = float(input("Enter Fire Rate:"))

    #from user inputs establish how many shots it takes to reduce health to or below zero
    if ((health / dps).is_integer()) is False: #checks if the stk value will be a float
        stk = int(health / dps) + 1 #since stk value is a float go up to next whole number. 33dps doesn't kill in 3 shots.
    else: #if stk value is an integer, establishes stk variable
        stk = health / dps

    delay_in_seconds = float(60 / spm)
    # delay_in_milliseconds = float(delay_in_seconds*1000)

    #establishes the time to kill in seconds, take one from stk to account for delay of gunfire
    ttki = ((stk - 1) * delay_in_seconds)

    print int((ttki * 1000)) / stk, int(ttki), stk,health, health/stk, range(int(stk))

    # establish progressbar
    progre = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient='horizontal', maximum=health, mode='determinate')
    progre.pack(fill=X)

    # test on how to test for frequency of updating GUI once I figure out how in the heck to build it
    def DPS_Timer():
        global counter
        print counter
        if counter != (stk-1):
            counter += 1
            progre.step(float((health/stk)))
            root.after(int(ttki*1000/stk), DPS_Timer)
        else:
            progre.stop()


    # establish GUI Button
    B1 = Button(root, text='start', command=DPS_Timer).pack(fill=X)

    root.mainloop()

main()
```